# Bitcoin p2p fees?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, binance

I brought bitcoin via binance p2p. However, I notice that if I buy say £1000 of bitcoin, the value is really less (say £600).

I am tryoing to understand why this is? Is this due to any fees?

Comment: Is “binance p2p” perhaps a market place for users to submit their own offers and bids? Is it possible that some user just submitted an offer that was far removed from the current spot price?

Comment: Yeah p2p is where users sell coins. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Among other things, there are exchanges and market places for buying bitcoin. Exchanges have a matching engine that resolves the best offers and bids against each other until there is a spread again. Market places allow users to post distinct offers that other users can pick from. It sounds to me like you did a market order against a very large spread or bought from a very unfavorable offer on a market place.